# How to query an observablecollection of tree structure?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observable collection of a tree structure with no fixed depth binding to my xaml,if "Parent" is my observablecollection, its structure is as follows. How do i query it to get to child4?

```
Parent
    --Child1
    --Child2
       --Child3
       --Child4
    --Child5
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Post some sample code and please be specific about what parts of the code you're having issues with.

Comment: Do you just want to query it or bind it to the UI too?